# I can't shade only one object

Tags: shaders

I can't shade just one object. What happens is I make some shader and it works, the problem is that it shades all objects. How do I shade just one object? If it helps, I am making a jello simulation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a difference between *materials* and *material slots*. By default, each object shares the same material slot when first created (Material). To add a new material slot to an object, click the plus button next to the material name box. This will let you give it a material that is different than the base material that all objects share.

[image: Mat1]

Next, press the plus button below the box to add a new material to that slot.

[image: Mat1a]

[image: Mat2]

Once the new material is made, you can make it the primary material on an object by picking its main material slot and changing the material in that slot by clicking the "globe" button and selecting it from the list.

[image: Mat3]

You can remove slots from objects by using the minus button to the right of the "Slot Name" box. Remember, the ability to have multiple slots is there for a reason, an object will often have multiple slots, with the materials in those slots assigned to different areas of the object.